# Find string in html with no html divider using php and selenium

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this html:

```
<div id="infos">
    NAME COMANY
    <br>
    35 South , Wimbledon
   <br>SA51 8RR London
   <br>***United Kingdom
   Phone: +##-##-####.####
   Fax: +##-##-###.####***
  <br>
  <a href="#">Website</a>
  <a href="#">Mail</a>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <strong>people</strong>
  <br>Mr. name.family
  <br>Ms. name.family
```

and I want **PHONE number** and Mail?
there is no divider between below item.

```
United Kingdom
Phone: +##-##-####.####
Fax: +##-##-###.####
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you can do actually is first try to get all the text inside your `div`, which you can simply get through below `Xpath`:-

```
//div/text()
```

This will result like below image:-

[image]

Then you can iterate on the `text` to get the desired one.

```
//div/text()[4]
```

This will get you the desired text.

[image]

Once you have the text, you can use your `PHP` code to process in the form you want.

Hope it helps!

**Dynamic Text**

If the text is dynamic and not coming on 4th position, then you can use something like below:-

```
//div/text()[contains(.,'***United')]
```

Comment: its generating html Dynamically, so phone is not always the fourth item text.